# Visual Studio 2012 bug on building?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

It's kinda strange - a solution that gets build in VS 2010 normally, in VS 2012 acts weird.
The solution has a few projects that reference each other.

The first time If I try to build, it throws bunch of "Metadata file c:......dll couldn't be found" errors, like projects build order broken or something

but if I just ignore those and build it again, I would see less errors, and if I build for the third time it would build without throwing any errors.

Absolutely the same solution opened in VS 2010 builds right away with no problems... wtf?

Comment: Is this just a complaint or do you have a question?  If the question is "how do I fix this?" then you'll need to reduce the problem to a minimal, self-contained example that we can use to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I had a similar error with vs2005 and vs2010 did you try to recreate the project?

Comment: The solution contains about 30 projects... Don't really want to recomposed it again. And James you're right not really a good question, but I'm just wondering if anybody saw already something similar

Comment: Having the same problems. It works most of the time, but suddenly gives build errors. Building each separate project one by one, then building the entire solution solves the problem for a few hours, then it appears again.

Comment: Seeing the same thing.  We have a large solution with ~100 projects.  It appears VS spawns processes to build separate projects concurrently, and they clash when trying to access resources, or they fail because dependent libraries are not built yet.